# DataGridView Not showing Data

Tags: c#, sql, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have the following code to display the data in a `DataGridView` from a  table. But the `DataGridView` is empty:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("sdgds");
            SqlCommand sCommand;
            SqlDataAdapter sAdapter;
            SqlCommandBuilder sBuilder;
            DataSet sDs;
            DataTable sTable;
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=test;" +
                                       "password=test;server=MOBILE01;" +
                                       "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                       "database=mydatabase; " +
                                       "connection timeout=30");
            myConnection.Open();


            sCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, myConnection);
            sAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sCommand);
            sBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sAdapter);
            sDs = new DataSet();

            sAdapter.Fill(sDs);


            sAdapter.Fill(sDs, "mytable");
            dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;

            dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
            myConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you didn't set your [`DataGridView.DataSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = sDs.Tables["mytable"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not assinged the `DataSource` to `gridview`

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = sDs.Tabes[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is just to populate DataGridView to display data, then you probably should get rid of Dataset, DataAdapter filling routine:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("sdgds");
            SqlCommand sCommand;
            SqlCommandBuilder sBuilder;
            DataTable sTable;
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=test;" +
                                       "password=test;server=MOBILE01;" +
                                       "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                       "database=mydatabase; " +
                                       "connection timeout=30");
            myConnection.Open();


            sCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, myConnection);

            /// here is the change - getting data in data reader and filling datatable directly with it.
            var reader = sCommand.ExecuteReader();
            sTable = new DataTable();
            sTable.Load(reader);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = sTable;
            dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;

            dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
            myConnection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @techno why showing message on form load? Is it required?